# expressions including functions for values in interval type for postgres

Tags: postgresql, intervals

Is there a way in postgres db. to have expression inside interval type ? , e.g. I can execute a query -

```
select (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval '1 second' * J0.C3) from T637 J0
```

Now , I need to be able to manipulate value of '1 second' dynamically , meaning '(1+2) seconds' fails for postgres , along with that the "value portion" value if it is getting derived via a function , and output of that function is some integer , I can't use that function in interval , e.g. interval `func(args) seconds`, how to achieve such dynamic "value portion" for "interval" in postgres db ?

Comment: The query that I build is generated dynamically by java code , ultimately the query that I want to build is - interval '((1-EXTRACT(day from (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + interval '1 second' * J0.C3 - interval '28800 seconds'))))Day' , I understood that it could be broken in parts , like - interval '1 day' - interval(rest of part in days) , now "rest of part in days" again broken into interval '1 day' * EXTRACT(day from (...)) and so on , but I cannot traverse the already generated query back , to break into format of , interval '1 second' * (some integer value)

Answer (score 1):

`interval '(1+2) seconds'` is not a valid expression. However, `interval '1 second' * 2` is valid.

So, to get the equivalent of `'(m+n) seconds'`, one would would typically do either:

```
(interval '1 second' * m) + (interval '1 second' * n)
```

or

```
(m+n) * interval '1 second'
```

likewise, if there is a function that returns a numeric value and we want an interval of that magnitude (with units of seconds), the following could be used:

```
func(args) * (interval '1 second')
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of "interval building", make_interval() is quite handy:

```
make_interval(secs => (1 + 2) * some_column);
```